# c++ dll windows plugin architecture approach

Tags: c++, dll, plugins

as the title suggests, I'm having trouble with my first approach to plugin architecture and I hope for some advice, but let me be specific...

Suppose you have a pure abstract class BASE with some defined methods...
Suppose also that you have a main executable, and a dll file dynamically linked at runtime with the main executable...
BASE is in a header file included in both the main exe and the dll...
BASE subclasses are defined in the dll, and their abstract methods implemented...
Main exe allocates an array of pointers to BASE.
That array is passed to the dll. The dll creates objects on the heap, and returns the array filled with pointers to instances of those objects.

The problem is, that when I try to call a member method of BASE on one of those instances on the main exe, (which should be overloaded in the dll by the derived class), I get an access violation error.
I'm not passing classes or anything c++ specific through the c interface I have
defined for the main executable and the dll... Just pointers...

This is just for academic purposes really, but still I'm toying with the idea that perhaps different people would create plug ins (dlls) for the main program, so compatibility is an issue. 
So I think it is a good idea to keep the dll's interface in c, wouldn't you agree?

I think the dll and the main executable share the same heap space, so
the pointers to the object instances should work, isn't that correct?

On the other hand, a pointer to an object would just give the main program
a place in memory where the instance's variables are stored, but no information about
its methods' code, which the main program knows nothing about, since it's defined in the dll.
So it's logical that without the address of the executable code, it can't
call the abstract classes' method implementation.
Is my speculation correct thus far?

I know I could use function pointers kept inside each object,
but wouldn't that destroy the nice built-in polymorphic mechanism of c++?

Another approach would be, since the abstract methods of BASE are known, to 
implement a c-style function (in the dll's c interface), for each BASE class'
methods, with an extra argument, the object's ptr. This way the implemented
method could be handled inside the dll on the specific object. I don't like this idea very much.
Makes the dll's interface bigger and a lot of c functions are used, almost
makes the handling of the derived classes c-style, or at least in need
of wrapping inside other c++ classes. What are your thoughts on it?

What I'm basically asking the community is: 
Is the way I'm trying to do it the correct approach? or are my thoughts completely wrong? Am I missing out something important?
What else would you suggest?

Thank you very much for your time and support.

***UPDATE:***
Since I can't in no way figure out what I'm doing wrong, I will resort to uploading my code...

Main Program - .cpp file

```
#include "feats.h"

using namespace std;
typedef void* (__cdecl *_connect)(void);

void addFeats(vector<feats::feat*> &vec, void* pluginDllRet) {
    size_t i = 0;
    feats::feat **retVal = (feats::feat**) pluginDllRet;
    while(retVal[i] != NULL) vec.push_back(retVal[i++]);
}

int main(void) {
    HINSTANCE dllFile = LoadLibrary("dllName.dll");
    if(dllFile == NULL) { /*error Handling*/ }

    _connect con = (_connect) GetProcAddress(dllFile, "_connect");
    if(con == NULL) { /*error Handling*/ }

    vector<feats::feat*> featsHolder;
    addFeats(featsHolder, con());

    for(size_t i = 0; i < featsHolder.size(); i++)
        cout << featsHolder[i]->getName() << "\n";
    FreeLibrary(dllFile );
}
```

Following is the dll file's .cpp file...

```
#include "feats.h"
using namespace feats;
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void* __cdecl _connect(void) {
        return executableCode();    //<- this is visible in main program
    }
}

namespace feats {
    class acrobatic : public feats::feat {
        public:
        std::string getName(void) {
            return "Acrobatic";
        }
    };

    class powerfull : public feats::feat {
        public:
        std::string getName(void) {
            return "Powerfull";
        }
    };
}

void* executableCode(void) {
    feats::feat **fts = new feats::feat*[3];
    fts[0] = new acrobatic;
    fts[1] = new powerfull;
    fts[2] = NULL;
    return (void*) fts;
}
```

And last but not least the header in both main program and the dll...

```
#ifndef FEATS_H
#define FEATS_H

#include <string>

namespace feats {
    class feat {
        public:
        virtual std::string getName(void) = 0;
    };
}
#endif
```

So with this presented I hope my problem is more clear... I tried to make it as compact as possible... So, thanks again for your help...

***UPDATE 2 - Solution***
As it seems the above code is correct and working... My problem, working on visual studio was that I compiled the dll in release mode, while the main program was in debug mode. Flipping that fixed the problem...
Such a simple error, causing such contemplation... Anyway,
I'm leaving the above code as an example for future searches...

Comment: You have to keep in mind that a virtual function is used via a function pointer. So there is no need to create C-style function pointers, you get exactly that by using an abstract base class.

Answer (score 5):

Just define you abstract interface in a header file:

```
class AbstractBase
{
public:
  virtual int SomeFunction() = 0;

  virtual int SomeOtherFunction() = 0;
};
```

In that header also define two C functions to create and destory a class:

```
AbstractBase *CreateClass();    

void DestroyClass(AbstractBase *data);
```

Inside you dll implement the concrete class:

```
class MyClass: AbstractBase
{
public:
    SomeFunction() {};
    virtual ~SomeFunction() {};

    virtual int SomeFunction() { return 1; }

    virtual int SomeOtherFunction() { return 1; }
};
```

Inside your dll also implement the create and destroy functions:

```
AbstractBase *CreateClass()
{
    return new SomeFunction();
}

void DestroyClass(AbstractBase *data);    
{
   delete data;
}
```

Now inside the main executable load the create an destroy dll 
entry points at run time.

Call the create entry point to get an object and talk to that
object using the abstract interface.

Call the destroy entry point to destroy the object.

Comment: jussij thank you for your answer... However that's not really what I'm looking for. As I explained above, the main program doesn't know, and doesn't even care about the "multiple" subclasses that get defined/derived from BASE class, in your example AbstractBase. Instead, I call a function that returns an array of lots of pointers to such base classes, which are created in the dll... So a createClass function is not useful... Besides, that model doesn't seem to be working... And having done my research I found a logical explanation for it... If you feel like it, please check my other points...

Comment: That model definitely works. I am the author of the Zeus IDE and I use that exact same pattern to implement generic code folding and generic scripting. For example the IDE is scriptable in about 7 or 8 languages (i.e. Python, Lua, VB Script etc), but as far as the IDE is concerned there is only one scripting language, as it talks to all the different scripting engines using the one and only interface. The same goes for the code folding.

Comment: I have updated my question, containing an example of the code I'm trying to implement, and where the exception is thrown.
Perhaps you have the time to have a quick look since you are experienced in the matter?

Comment: The _connect function in your code is almost identical to the CreateClass function found in my code. It just has a different name and a different return value. So if you implement my example from above with my  CreateClass but using you GetProcAddress to get the entry point it will work.